# Condition based on First Element of a group in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` with columns `[ShowOnAir, AfterPremier, ID, EverOnAir]`.

My condition is that

- if it is the first element of `groupby(df.ID)`
  then `if (df.ShowOnAir ==0 or df.AfterPremier == 0)`, then `EverOnAir  = 0`
- `else EverOnAir = 1`

I am not sure how to compare the first element of the `groupby`, with elements of the orignal dataframe `df`.

would really appreciate if I could get help in it ,

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get a row number for your groups by using `cumsum`, then you can do your logic on the resulting dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1],[1],[2],[2],[2]])
df['n']=1
df.groupby(0).cumsum()

   n
0  1
1  2
2  1
3  2
4  3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create new column `EverOnAir` filled `1`. Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `ID` and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) custom function `f`, [where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) find first element of columns by [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) and fill `0`:

```
print df
   ShowOnAir  AfterPremier ID
0          0             0  a
1          0             1  a
2          1             1  a
3          1             1  b
4          1             0  b
5          0             0  b
6          0             1  c
7          1             0  c
8          0             0  c

def f(x):
    #print x
    x['EverOnAir'].iat[0] = np.where((x['ShowOnAir'].iat[0] == 0 ) |
                                     (x['AfterPremier'].iat[0] == 0), 0, 1)
    return x   

df['EverOnAir'] = 1  
print df.groupby('ID').apply(f)
   ShowOnAir  AfterPremier ID  EverOnAir
0          0             0  a          0
1          0             1  a          1
2          1             1  a          1
3          1             1  b          1
4          1             0  b          1
5          0             0  b          1
6          0             1  c          0
7          1             0  c          1
8          0             0  c          1
```